# Segregate a Dynamic Structured Data

Tags: python, sorting, machine-learning

I am having a large amount of data (around 20K lines) as shown below.

```
Caller1 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller2 1:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller3 2:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller1 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller5 3:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller3 4:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller2 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller1 7:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller12 9:39AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller14 8:36AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller15 2:39AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller16 3:32AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
```

I am looking for a way to segregate the data based on the `CallerID` as shown below:

```
Caller1 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller1 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller1 7:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
---------------------------------
Caller2 1:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19
Caller2 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-1
---------------------------------
.
.
```

I initially used to have this data stored as a `dictionary` and any new data was added to that dictionary

I am having troubles segregating as the initial parameter `CallerID` is also variable.

My Code:

```
>>> input = [('caller1', 'data....'),('caller2','data,,,,,)
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> res = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in input: res[k].append(v)
```

I cannot use this as the dataset is too large

Are there any packages in Python which will segregate the data based on the first word of a sentence?

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried?

Comment: Thank you for the response. the one I tried is when I know the data Example; Caller1. But here I do not know caller1 also. This is all dynamic data coming into the system. so could not know how to start for this type of data...

Comment: At a high level that code is like this: >>> input = [('caller1', 'data....'),('caller2','data,,,,,)
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> res = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in input: res[k].append(v)  ....and again work  on this list. I cannot  use this as its all dynamic and large data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach, store the data in a dictionary of list with key as the string that you want to group with ie Caller1, Caller2 etc.

```
     data = ["Caller1 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller2 1:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller3 2:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller1 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller5 3:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller3 4:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller2 5:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller1 7:30AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller12 9:39AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller14 8:36AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller15 2:39AM Mexico USA 2-22-19",
            "Caller16 3:32AM Mexico USA 2-22-19"]

    grouped_data = {}

    # ITERATE THE INPUT AND STORE DATA WITH KEY IN DICTIONARY OF LIST 
    for x in data:
        temp: list = []
        key = x.split(' ')[0]
        if key in grouped_data:
            temp = grouped_data.get(key)
        temp.append(x)
        grouped_data[key] = temp

    # PRINT THE DATA AS GROUPED
    for k, v in grouped_data.items():
        print(f"data for {k}")
        for d in v:
            print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you . Can you suggest me any other package/solution I can use when I am having lots of data. I liked your approach. I tried in another way as mentioned.

Comment: May be you can use panda's I am not sure, I haven't used it, seen it in many places though not sure if that's what you are looking for